# how to add shared library to QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a project which involves the use of two libraries. I've tried to add the libraries to be included into my .pro file, but when i compile i receive a "cannot find -lmylib1".

```
INCLUDEPATH += ./lib/mylib1 \
               ./lib/mylib2

LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/lib/mylib1" -lmylib1 \
        -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/lib/mylib2" -lmylib2
```

The directory structure is as below.

```
Myproject.pro
lib (directory)
     mylib1 (directory)
         mylib1.so
     mylib2 (directory)
         mylib2.so
```

Comment: Did you add these Libraries from QtCreator or did you edit the .pro file manually? Normally you can click on "add Library" on a project and it automatically inserts the correct lines in the project file

Comment: added these lines manually. When i try to add it by using "add library" it doesn't show the files as being able to be added

Comment: probably because QtCreator only searches for files with the names "lib*.so". So "mylib1.so" does not get recognized as a library

Comment: thanks that worked

Answer (score 1):

To complete @dave comment, it is not only that Qt Creator only searches for files with the names "lib*.so". It is the default behavior for linkers on UNIX-like systems.

Quoting the documentation for the *ld* linker:

> `-larchive`
>
> [...] ld will search its path-list for
>   occurrences of **libarchive.a** for every archive specified. On systems
>   which support shared libraries, ld may also search for libraries with
>   extensions other than .a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS systems, ld
>   will search a directory for a library with an extension of .so before
>   searching for one with an extension of .a. By convention, a .so
>   extension indicates a shared library. [...] This type of archive searching is standard for Unix linkers.

So if your library does not match the `lib*.a` or `lib*.so` patterns, it is expected that both Qt Creator and the linker do not find it.